# Request aggreation possbility with 3scale

Tags: 3scale

I started to develop a applciation with spring.
We are checking for an api gateway, we will surely go with 3scale.

I'm checking to do Request aggreation but I don't find how to do it with 3scale

Answer (score 0):

If you mean aggregating the responses coming from different backends, that at the moment is not possible with only 3scale gateway.

3scale adopts an approach which is of separation of concerns, so only Header content is manipulated, to keep the gateway performant.

My suggestion would be to add a simple camel integration to handle this transformation.